# ng-repeat value array angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Sorry for the title, this is my first post.

OK, my problem is, I have this JSON:

```
   {
  "nodes" : [
    {
      "node" : {
        "Title" : "this is a title",
        "slideshowImage" : [
          {
            "src" : "imagen.png",
            "alt" : ""
          },
          {
            "src" : "imagen.png",
            "alt" : ""
          },
          {
            "src" : "imagen.png",
            "alt" : ""
          },
          {
            "src" : "imagen.png",
            "alt" : ""
          }
        ],
        "Thumbnail" : {
          "src" : "imagen.png",
          "alt" : ""
        },
        "id" : "28"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I get a `ng-repeat` to `slideshowImage`

Ex: `ng-repeat="node in items.slideshowImage"`

`{{node.node.slideshowImage.src}}`

Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: You should do ng-repeat="item in nodes.node.slideshowImage" and {{ item.src }}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your object is assigned to `nodes` object, then it would be simple like below.

```
ng-repeat="image in nodes.node.slideshowImage"
```

Comment: @JulianChabrillon click on tick icon below upvote button, so that this answer get accepted. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna ng-repeat in view Directly Like following :-

```
      <div ng-repeat="N1 in sampleData.nodes"> 
          <div ng-repeat="N2 in N1.node.slideshowImage">
                 {{N2.src}}
           </div>
      </div> <!-- Looped down to Subnodes For your Understanding --!>
```

Or Just Save  it in to a scope Quick way :-

```
$scope.quickData=$scope.sampleData.nodes[0].node.slideshowImage; // as per data length
```

Now Roll it (ng-repeat) :-

```
     <div ng-repeat="quick in quickData">
               {{quick.src}}
         </div>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/EhuLmjzNa5srX2AV2gqT?p=preview

Both results are saved in Plunker

Happy Learning !!

Comment: doesn't make sense repeating the properties in node object. You have one too many nested repeats

Comment: showed diff ways to loop it of course one of it bit lengthy way,Just for beginner understanding purposes and For some JSON Iterate  Experience

Comment: Still doesn't make sense. Just loop over array `N1.node.slideshowImage`.

Comment: http://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=64b978cda1cca5eb1e59c9564f58b418 pls take a look it here

Comment: @ charlietfl  yes that is precise ..  updated :-) as a beginner her can experiment and undestand himself for a quicker solution ..

Comment: Thanks all for yours comments! I did it in a similar wey but not for one objet :)

Answer (score 0):

You should do

```
ng-repeat="item in nodes.node.slideshowImage"
```

and in your views

```
{{ item.src }}
```